# Web/msdeploy sync from IIS to IISExpress fails

Tags: iis, msdeploy, iis-express, webdeploy

I have a a web site on a IIS on a remote machine. I would like to sync the website on the remote server to a local IISExpress. Currently I do not have the site on my local IISExpress. I am using the following `msdeploy.exe` command line (Here I formatted it in several lines, but of course the actual command is a single line):

```
msdeploy.exe 
 -verb:sync 
 -source:webApp="mysubdomain.mydomain.com",computername=mycomputer,userName=myuser,password=mypassword
 -dest:auto 
 -apphostconfigdir=C:\Users\steen\Documents\IISExpress\config 
 -webserverdir="c:\program files (x86)\IIS Express"
```

I get following error returned:

```
Error: Application Definition with path 'mysubdomain.mydomain.com' does not exist.
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Do I need to have the site on my local IISExpress before I can sync (is there any workaround if I must have it locally first?)?

Answer (score 1):

In the -source argument, try using the name of the web application for *webApp* (e.g. `webApp="wordpress"`) and specifying the URL for your server in the *computername* argument. I don't think you need to have the site locally to begin with, but of course you'll need to have whatever web application the site uses installed locally.

Links: webApp: [Web Deploy webApp Provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418391%28WS.10%29.aspx); computername: [Web Deploy Provider Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569001%28WS.10%29.aspx).